# Linq Nested Query Issue with decimal type

Tags: c#, linq

I'm applying this following query in C#:

```
var query = from b in db.SalesOrderHeaders
        where b.SubTotal >  (from c in db.Employees
                             join v in db.EmployeePayHistories 
                         on c.BusinessEntityID equals v.BusinessEntityID
                             select v.Rate)
        select new
        {
            b.BusinessEntityID,
            b.SubTotal,
        };
```

But an error is returned: `linq and face error: Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'System.Linq.IQueryable<decimal>'`.

Both `b.subtotal` and `v.rate` are decimal type and I want to compare these two. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please take more care in formatting your questions. The code is all over the place. I'll fix it up this time, but really you should do it when you first post the question.

Comment: ok thanks i m new to stackoverflow

Comment: The problem is that your nested query fetches a *sequence* - and it doesn't even mention `b`. It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve, without knowing your schema.

Comment: its adventure work Database

Comment: Well which value within that query are you interested in? Do you understand the problem?

Comment: @JonSkeet All the Sales which were greater than the highest employee salary thats my query problem

Comment: Your query doesn't say anything about the *highest* employee salary though, does it? I suspect you need an `order by v.Rate descending` in your nested query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add Max at the end of the inner query:

```
var query = from b in db.SalesOrderHeaders
    where b.SubTotal >  (from c in db.Employees
                         join v in db.EmployeePayHistories 
                     on c.BusinessEntityID equals v.BusinessEntityID
                         select v.Rate).Max()
    select new
    {
        b.BusinessEntityID,
        b.SubTotal,
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the inner query returns `IEnumerable<decimal>` rather than a single value.

If there is guaranteed to be only one record returned from your inner query, you could simply call `Single()`:

```
where b.SubTotal > (from c in db.Employees
                    join v in db.EmployeePayHistories
                    on c.BusinessEntityID equals v.BusinessEntityID
                    select v.Rate).Max()
```

If more than one value can be returned from the inner query, then you'll need to figure out exactly how that comparison should work and apply the appropriate aggregate function.

Comment: I was going to post an answer like this, but it would seem odd for a join with *no* conditions on to only have a single entry.

Comment: basically thats my query All the Sales which were greater than the highest employee salary

Comment: he methods 'Single' and 'SingleOrDefault' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.   This exception came .

Comment: @DanishAhmad - Then take the suggestion and try FirstOrDefault. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks JUSTIN WORKED NOW WITH FIRST OR DEFUALT

Comment: @DanishAhmad: Define "worked" here... the query ran, but given your comment, I don't think it's necessarily doing what you wanted, because you're never finding the *highest* employee salary.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I'm with you on this one. The query may execute, but there's no way it's doing anything with the max salary. Maybe a call to Max instead of FirstOrDefault?

Comment: Yup, using Max is a much better idea than my OrderByDescending followed by First :)